# Show the centre of a group $G$ is the intersection of the normalizer of all elements in group $G$

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, finite-groups

We know that centre of a group $G$ is defined as
$Z=\{z\in G\mid zx=xz\forall x\in G\}$ and the normaliser $N(a)=\{x\in G\mid ax=xa\}$

So what is the difference between the two and how do I take on comprehending a proof if I'm asked to prove something which involves intersection of elements

Comment: Well, one usually does not define the normalizer of a single element; one defines the normalizer of a **subgroup**, and the normalizer of a subgroup $H$ is $N_G(H) = \{x\in G\mid xHx^{-1}=H\}$. As to the difference between the center of $G$ and the **centralizer** of an element $a$, to be in $Z$ an element $z$ must commute with **every** element of $G$; to be in the cetralizer of $a$ it only  needs to commute with $a$. Compare "needs to be friends with everyone" and "needs to be friends with this specific person".

Comment: You aren't asked to take intersection of elements. You are asked to take intersection of **sets**.

Comment: Are you sure this is called normalizer? If so, it's pretty non standard. Usually it's called the centralizer of the element. A normalizer is what is described in the comment above.

Comment: I agree, they are called centralisers. In general, they are stabilisers of a group action, which here is the conjugation action on the group itself. "how do I take on comprehending a proof if I'm asked to prove something which involves intersection of elements" - use the definitions and look for the "for all" in the definition of the center. This can be formulated as an intersection of sets.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:intersection-theory].

Answer (score 0):

This indeed immediately follows from the definitions $$\bigcap_{g \in G} N(g) = \bigcap_{g \in G} \{z \in G \mid gz = zg\} = \{z \in G \mid \forall g \in G: gz = zg\} = Z.$$ The difference is the $\forall$ and in general $$\bigcap_{x \in X} \{a \in A \mid P(x,a) \text{ is true} \} = \{a \in A \mid \forall x \in X : P(x,a) \text{ is true}\}.$$

Comment: The question seems to be "what is the difference" and something-something about "intersection of elements", not whether the equation is true.

Comment: I think the answer explains what was asked. The intersection arises by saying "for all" in the definition of the center. The OP has a problem with this intersection.